# Why doesn't Al Hanisim Mention the Miracle of the Oil?

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, miracle

Why is there no mention of the miracle of the candles burning for eight nights in Al Hanisim?

Comment: (The lighting is mentioned, but its true that the miracle is not spelled out.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somewhat related to Shalom's answer, the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l explains ([Likkutei Sichos, vol. 25, pp. 235](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16051&pgnum=248)ff) that the miracle of the oil (a spiritual victory) overshadows the miracle of beating the Greek armies (a physical one) - because the latter was itself part of a larger spiritual war: they tried to make us "forget Your Torah and abandon the decrees of Your Will"; ordered the Jews to "write on the horn of an ox that you have no portion in the G-d of Israel"; etc.

So when we want to mention and describe the miracle of the military victory, we have to omit mention of the miracle of the oil. Conversely, when the Gemara explains מאי חנוכה, it mentions the victory only incidentally.

Answer (score 5):

Al HaNisim was designed to be placed in the blessing of "Modim", in which we give thanks

> for our lives which are in Your hands, for our souls which are under Your watch, for Your miracles each day to us, for Your wonders and kindness at each moment, night, morning, and afternoon ...

The focus is on the "everyday" miracles that occur within the bounds of what we call nature.  So *Al HaNisim* likewise focuses on the military victory, which wasn't (blatantly) supernatural.

(This isn't my answer; I heard it from someone contemporary whose name I sadly don't recall.)

Comment: one of my favorite answers in Ner l'meah, about why 8 days, when the miracle was really only 7 days: Whenever we light oil and it burns, it is a natural "everyday" miracle, which sometimes requires supernatural miracles to focus our attention on the mundane ones.

Answer (score 3):

A wonderful answer to this question us given in the sefer Tal Oros by Rabbi Yehudah Tuvia Guttentag (Tavyomi). The full text in English can be found [here](http://www.shlomokluger.com/Other-Books/Tal-Oros/Chanukah-1.html), but the following excerpt contains the essential points:

> After the great victory of
>   Yehudah the Maccabee against the many and strong Greek troops and over
>   the multitude of Hellenists, and after the purification of the
>   sanctuary, the rebuilding of the altar, the miracle of the flask of oil
>   and the celebration of the re-inauguration for eight days, Yehudah the
>   Maccabee and his Beis Din, the Great Beis Din that was called at that
>   time “the Beis Din of the Chashmonoim” (see Avodah Zorah 36),
>   they wanted to make a remembrance of these salvations and wonders, and
>   to establish these days of Chanukah as a festival for the generations
>   with Hallel and thanksgiving.
>
> However, on this point there was a confusing problem; on what
>   to substantiate and base this festival? For which remembrance to
>   establish it? If to commemorate the great victory of the few against
>   the
>   many, and the weak against the strong - this would not be in accordance
>   with the rules of the Torah, because a festival with Hallel and
>   thanksgiving can only be fixed for a completely unnatural
>   miracle, as mentioned above. If to commemorate the miracle of the flask
>   of
>   oil that only contained enough oil to light for one day, but by a
>   miracle they managed to light from it for eight days, - this is an
>   ‘inside miracle’, a miracle which occurred only in the sanctuary, in
>   the
>   presence of a handful of Kohanim whose day of service it was, or whose
>   week it was, in a place where it is totally forbidden for non-Kohanim
>   to enter. If in earlier, very righteous generations little importance
>   and value were given to ‘inside’ miracles like these, all the more so
>   in
>   that generation where there were numerous Hellenists. Certainly the
>   general population would not believe in this miracle; they would have
>   no regard for it and would not celebrate any festival in order to
>   remember
>   it.
>
> After great deliberation, Yehudah the Maccabee and his Beis
>   Din
>   came to a decision: they would establish this festival of Chanukah with
>   Hallel
>   and thanksgiving and candle lighting, but without giving a
>   reason and substantiation for establishing this new festival, similar
>   to
>   other decrees and safeguards that were sometimes issued without
>   explanation. Like the gemara Avodah Zorah 30 says, “When they made a
>   decree
>   in Eretz Yisrael they did not reveal the reason for twelve months,
>   perhaps somebody might disagree with the reason, and the people would
>   come to make light of the decree”, and thus undermine the
>   decree.
>
> With
>   this the Beis Din of the Chashmonoim have satisfied everybody. Because
>   those
>   who knew the Torah, who were expert in its laws and knew that a
>   festival with Hallel and thanksgiving
>   is only established for a non-natural miracle, they would trust the
>   testimony
>   of the Kohanim in the Beis Hamikdosh, amongst whom were certainly some
>   of the great Beis Din. They would not doubt even for a moment the
>   miracle of the flask of oil. The general populace, in the absence of an
>   explicit reason, would think that the festival was established as
>   a remembrance of the salvations and victories, and the lighting of
>   candles is to remember the renewed lighting of the menorah in the Beis
>   Hamikdosh. Let them think what they will, as long as they observe the
>   festival with all the its commandments, according to Halachah.
>
> This
>   corresponds to the text of Al Hanissim. There, also, everything is
>   mentioned in a vague style - the
>   wars, the victories, together with the purification of the sanctuary
>   and
>   the lighting of the candles, which is based on the miracle of the flask
>   of oil. But this miracle is not
>   mentioned explicitly, because this prayer is for everybody, and
>   therefore they intentionally concealed this reason of the ‘inside’
>   miracle because of
>   ignoramuses.